# Deep nested hash difference in Ruby

Tags: ruby, associative-array

I wants find the difference between two different Hash.

```
a = {"3"=>{"passenger_type"=>"ADT", "the_order"=>"3", "last"=>"ARUN", "first"=>"KUMAR", "middle"=>nil}, "2"=>{"passenger_type"=>"ADT", "the_order"=>"2", "last"=>"JONES", "first"=>"MAXIM", "middle"=>nil}, "1"=>{"passenger_type"=>"ADT", "the_order"=>"1", "last"=>"RAM", "first"=>"TODD", "middle"=>nil}}

b = {1=>{"middle"=>nil, "the_order"=>"1", "passenger_type"=>"BDT", "last"=>"RAM", "first"=>"TODD"}, 2=>{"middle"=>nil, "the_order"=>"2", "passenger_type"=>"ADT", "last"=>"JONES", "first"=>"MAXIM"}, 3=>{"middle"=>nil, "the_order"=>"3", "passenger_type"=>"ADT", "last"=>"ARUN", "first"=>"KUMAR"}}
```

and the resultant hash or array should be like the following

```
{1=>{"middle"=>nil, "the_order"=>"1", "passenger_type"=>"BDT", "last"=>"RAM", "first"=>"TODD"}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following gives the answer, but not sure if it suits your real problem. You may need to refine your posts to let others know the details of your problem.

```
b.select{|k, v| v != a[k.to_s]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Arie Shaw. I was trying some complex logic on it.but you did it in a single line.

Comment: I see this single line of beauty, and cry, thinking of `array_udiff()` in PHP, and the dozens of lines of code required to accomplish the same thing.